# Why does `htop` display `$'\t'` as `?` in `sort` command?

Tags: sort, escape-characters, htop

I was running a pipe command with one section being the following:

```
sort -t $'\t'  -T . -k1,1g
```

When I was monitoring `htop` I saw this instead:

[image]

What is the reason behind this? Does this mean my command is wrong or is there something wrong with `htop`?

Comment: Important to remember that the command line that htop retrieved from procfs and is displaying doesn't contain the (shell-specific) four-character `$'\t'` sequence but instead just a 1-character tab literal that the shell parsed that sequence into.

Comment: (And unlike bash, POSIX sh doesn't have any way to write a tab with only printable characters, so there isn't really a good portable rendering available)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There’s nothing wrong with your command, [`htop` replaces control characters with question marks](https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/blob/29f0b3c5e1184421ee7796ab2e1841733c45f403/RichString.c#L143):

```c
(((unsigned char)data_c[j]) >= 32 ? ((unsigned char)data_c[j]) : '?')
```

(characters with values less than 32 are control characters).

Answer (score 1):

The htop process manager displays `$'\t'` as `?` in the sort command because it interprets the `\t` as a tab character, which is not a valid sorting option.

In the sort command, `\t` is used as a delimiter to specify the field that the command should sort by. However, in htop, it is not a valid delimiter and is therefore displayed as ? in the sort column.

You can try to use the -k option to specify the sort field and the -t option to specify the delimiter. For example, `htop -u -p -k 2,2 -t ' '` sorts by the 2nd field using a space as a delimiter.